# How can I get an attribute value in xml using xml-rs?

Tags: xml, rust, attributes, xml-rs

I have a large xml file and I want to print a particular attribute value name id under species tag. I have written this code

```
fn parse_fn(filename: &str) {
    let file = File::open(filename).unwrap();
    let file = BufReader::new(file);
    let parser = EventReader::new(file);
    for e in parser {
        match e {
            Ok(XmlEvent::StartElement { name, .. }) => {
                if name.local_name=="species"{
                    println!("{}",);
                }
            }
            Err(e) => {
                println!("Error: {}", e);
                break;
            }
            _ => {}
        }
    }
```

I am unable to figure out how to get that particular attribute value here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`StartElement`](https://docs.rs/xml-rs/0.8.3/xml/reader/enum.XmlEvent.html#variant.StartElement) enum variant has an `attributes` field which is a `Vec<OwnedAttribute>`, and [`OwnedAttribute`](https://docs.rs/xml-rs/0.8.3/xml/attribute/struct.OwnedAttribute.html) has a `value: String` field as well as a `name: OwnedName` field, and [`OwnedName`](https://docs.rs/xml-rs/0.8.3/xml/name/struct.OwnedName.html) has a `local_name: String` field. So, it'd probably look something like this:

```rust
match e {
    Ok(XmlEvent::StartElement { name, attributes, .. }) => {
        if name.local_name == "species" {
            for attr in attributes {
                if attr.name.local_name == "id" {
                    println!("{}", attr.value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or, with iterators the loop could be replaced with

```rust
attributes
    .iter()
    .filter(|attr| attr.name.local_name == "id")
    .for_each(|attr| println!("{}", attr));
```